# ui-if clashing with ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, prototypal-inheritance

Very simple code:

```
    <div ui-if="showMemberId">
        <input ng-model="memberId" ng-change="test()" id="memberId" name="memberId" class="text" type="text">
    </div>
```

With this for the controller:

```
$scope.memberId = 'SDF';
$scope.test = function test(){
    console.log($scope.memberId);
};
$scope.showMemberId = true;
```

Bizarrely, the `ng-change` works but not the `ng-model`. When I type into the input, it just logs the string  `SDF` to the console over and over because the model isn't changing.

Any ideas?

Comment: `ui-if` is one of many directives that create a new scope, and because your `ng-model` is a primitive, it won't be accessible in the way an object would be.  This is an example of one of the most commonly encountered issues in angular, which is always solved with the "always use a dot" rule.

Comment: golden rule in angular is always use an object in `ng-model` so you don't break bindings on primitives

Comment: further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Comment: also, unless my facts are wrong, `ui-if` was removed from more current versions of the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `ui-if` is creating a child scope like `ng-if` does. So the outer `memberId` scope will be different than `ng-model` present inside the `ui-if`.
In such cases you need to follow the `dot rule` while defining `ng-model`. Basically when it creates a child scope, its protypically inherited from parent scope. And `prototypal inheritance` works on `object` type not on `primitive types`

To make it working you need to define object inside controller like `$scope.model ={}` & define all the property in it .

**Markup**

```
<div ui-if="showMemberId">
    <input ng-model="model.memberId" ng-change="test()" 
     id="memberId" name="memberId" class="text" type="text"/>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.model = {}; //made an object type model
```

> I'd encourage you to use `ng-if` instead of `ui-if`, as angular does
>   provide the same functionality.

Comment: @Aerovistae glad to help you..Thanks :)